# Running Daily R Jobs on AWS while saving money

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cron

My goal is to get refreshed NFL play by play on a daily basis.

I currently use the R package `nflscrapr` (https://github.com/maksimhorowitz/nflscrapR).

My current refresh script looks like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(nflscrapr)
library(aws.s3)

source('https://github.com/leesharpe/nfldata/blob/master/code/plays.R')

### ...other data manipulations...

### save to AWS S3 bucket

### FINISH!
```

which updates the NFL play by play data and saves to an AWS S3 instance. Thus, I'm able to access the data on different machines. This is fine (and major props to the `nflscrapr` community and Lee Sharpe), but I want to create a cron job on AWS to run this daily.

There are many ideas of how I should do this, like running AWS Lambda to kick off the job; however, this refresh of NFL data can be a long process that takes upwards of 30 minutes. According to the AWS site (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/), Lambda can only run functions for 15 minutes with a maximum of 3 GB RAM, so that option is completely out.

Another idea is to create an entire EC2 instance to run this code, and schedule a cron job every morning to kick off the script. But if a simple EC2 with 2 CPU, 8 GB RAM (t2.Large) was always running and waiting for the cron job, this would cost about $70/month, which is not worth it for me.

Since this job takes about thirty minutes and only needs to be run once during the day, is there a way (on a daily basis) to

1. start the EC2 right before the cron job
2. the cron job kicks off the R script, saves the refreshed data to an S3
3. terminate the EC2 instance

Or possibly create and destroy a new EC2 instance after it has run this script every day?

This could potentially save me a lot of money.

Comment: interesting how saving money topics crawled into programming forums

Comment: Why do you need a machine that size?  It sounds like you've got a low CPU, non-time critical task.  A t3.nano will cost about USD $3.75 / month.  You could reduce the cost by having a Lambda start it daily and have the instance do one thing but how much time are you going to put in to save $2 / month out of less than $4?

Comment: So I tried running this program on t3.nano, micro all the way up to medium with the same problems: the processes kept getting killed by the system. The only way I was able to avoid the system kill is to run this on a t3.large.